# How to join 5 tables with IF conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 5 tables through book_id. I tried:

```
 SELECT booked_room_info . * , booking_info . * , hotel_info.name as
 hotelname,hotel_info.address as hoteladdress,hotel_info.contact as
 hotelcontact , personal_info . *,room_registration.room_name as
 roomname,room_registration.price as roomprice,room_registration.price as
 roomprice,room_registration.description as
 roomdescription,room_registration.image as roomimage
    FROM booked_room_info
    JOIN booking_info ON booking_info.booking_id = booked_room_info.booking_id
    JOIN hotel_info ON hotel_info.id = booking_info.hotel_id
    JOIN personal_info ON personal_info.booking_id = booked_room_info.booking_id
    JOIN room_registration ON room_registration.hotel_id = booking_info.hotel_id
    WHERE booked_room_info.booking_id= 1
```

But if i have 2 booking on booking_id = 1 but it fetched 10 result. I think I should make a if condition like. If `(booked.room_type && book_info.hotel_id)` is same then only fetch rows from room_registration but how can I aacomplish it.

```
booked_room_info
------
id | booking_id | room_type | check_in | check_out
1  |  1         | delux     | 2015/1/2 | 2015/1/5
booking_info
---------
id | booking_id | hotel_id | user_id 
 1 |  1         |  2       |  1 

hotel_info
----------
id |   name    | address | user_id
 2 |palm hotel | newyork | 1

personal_info 
-------------
id  |full_name    | address | nationality | booking_id
 1  | sushil stha | new york | smth       |  1

room_registration
-----------------
id | room_name | price | image   | hotel_id  | user_id
 1 |  delux    | 1000  |room.jpg |  2        |  1
```

Comment: @rtruszk i had added some sample data. Now i want to select all data with  reference to `booking_id`. In some table it doesnot contain `booking_id` directly so it needed to join from more another table how can i do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your last join:

```
JOIN room_registration ON room_registration.hotel_id = booking_info.hotel_id
```

You are joining these tables using `hotel_id` column. There are probably 5 rows in `room_registration` table with `hotel_id=2`. So after joining you receive `2*5=10` rows instead of expected 2.

So you should join with this table in different way.
If you want to join every row with exacly one row from `room_registration` table then you have to specify more precise join condition.

To join `room_registration` table properly you may add `room_registration_id` column to `booking_info` table. Then you can join using:

```
JOIN room_registration ON room_registration.id = booking_info.room_registration_id
```

Comment: yes this is what my issues was. You caught me right. So how can i make my join more precise. Please help. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`'s, removed the duplicate field.

```
SELECT 
bri.*, 
bi.*, 
hi.name AS hotelname, hi.address as hoteladdress, hi.contact AS hotelcontact, 
pi.*, 
rr.room_name AS roomname, rr.price AS roomprice, rr.description AS roomdescription, rr.image AS roomimage
FROM booked_room_info bri
INNER JOIN booking_info bi ON bri.booking_id = bi.booking_id
INNER JOIN hotel_info hi ON bi.hotel_id  = hi.id
INNER JOIN personal_info pi ON bri.booking_id = pi.booking_id
INNER JOIN room_registration rr ON bi.hotel_id = rr.hotel_id
WHERE bri.booking_id = 1
```

Comment: This didn't gave me aspected result.

Comment: @HomnathBagale What was the issue with the result?